# PHP cURL follow post location

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm using a payment form service where I need to set up a form with hidden fields with given names. When submitted, my form posts to the payment service which redirects me to their form based on the form post data.

Because of an issue I'm having with properly encrypting my password for the service, I'm trying to do this from a PHP script instead with curl. After my request though, I am not forwarded to the form, it just remains on my php page as a blank page

```
$username = "[removed]";
$password = "[removed]";

$url = '[removed]';
$fields = array(
    'Mode' => urlencode('PaymentForm'),
    'Login' => urlencode($username),
    'Password' => urlencode($password),
    'ReceiptUrl' => urlencode("[removed]"),
    'Description' => urlencode($_POST['Description']),
    'TotalAmt' => urlencode($_POST['TotalAmt']),
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from this in your logfiles? One possible problem is `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` if you don't have the certificate set up as trusted - see http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: No errors. The script executes successfully, it just does not forward to the next page. The page I'm posting to is the same host as the origin, so I wouldn't think certificates should not be an issue

Comment: What's the output of `echo curl_getinfo($ch)` after `curl_exec($ch)`?